# Bootstrap column messed up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap's grid system to make a responsive banner. The banner is split into 3 sections, `banner-left`, `banner-right-top` and `banner-right-bottom`. This is what it should look like:
[image]

But I seem to be getting this:
[image]

The white spaces on the `col-sm-4` grid. Can anyone help??

Also, here's my code for the banner.

```css
banner {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-4 {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
.banner,
.row {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.btn-banner {
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 10px !important;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-out;
}
.btn-banner:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #2c3e50;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in;
}
.banner .row .banner-left,
.col-sm-8 {
  background: url(http://www.wgcafe.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/a-vintage-red-background-with-a-crisscross-mesh-pattern-and-grunge-stains-wanlop-sonngam.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 800px;
}
.banner .row .banner-left,
.col-sm-8 .text {
  padding: 127px 5% 127px 10% !important;
}
.banner .row .col-sm-8 .text h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
.banner .row .col-sm-8 .text p {
  color: #fafbfb;
}
.banner>.banner-right,
.col-sm-4>.banner-right-top {
  background: url(http://xyer.co/wallpaper/19/1/red-blue-free.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 400px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important
}
.banner>.banner-right,
.col-sm-4>.banner-right-top .text {
  padding: 162px 10% 160px 20% !important;
}
.banner>.banner-right,
.col-sm-4>.banner-right-top .text h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
.banner>.banner-right,
.col-sm-4>.banner-right-bottom {
  background: url(http://art.ngfiles.com/images/189000/189626_nondual_red-and-blue-emissions.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 400px !important;
}
.banner>.banner-right,
.col-sm-4>.banner-right-bottom .text {
  padding: 89px 10% 89px 20% !important;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="banner">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="banner-left col-sm-8">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>WE ARE AN ELECTRICAL &amp MAINTENANCE COMPANY</h2>
        <p>Based in London and Kent regions.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a class="btn-banner" href="about">FIND OUT MORE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-right col-sm-4">
      <div class="banner-right-top">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>WE ARE A PROFESSIONAL TEAM</h3> 
          <br />
          <br />
          <a class="btn-banner" href="contact">GET IN TOUCH TODAY</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="banner-right-bottom">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>WE PROVIDE MANY TYPES OF ELECTRICAL INSTALLATION, INCLUDING COMMERCIAL, INDUSTRIAL AND DOMESTIC.</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The one thing that allowed this to work was CSS.. `*{margin:0; padding:0;}`, but that ruined everything else on the page apart from the banner. Any other alternatives to fix this??

Comment: You have quite a few errors in your CSS. However, the biggest problem is you haven't included the background images in your snippet, thus rendering your banner white on white. Please update your snippet or at least post links to your background images in the comments and i'll do it for you.

Comment: I have updated with new images now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it up for you:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/yeyMjo

You used containers and content elements but were trying to absolutely position content with pixel padding. That will break on different size screens. Use percentages like this:

```
// This is your content, pad element relative to the container
// I used percentages so, again, this would be relative to the viewport and potentially reusable
.banner .row .banner-left,.col-sm-8 .text{
  padding: 25% 20%;
}
```

I used `vh` (viewport height) units to size your boxes appropriately to the viewport. This is a more efficient way of doing what you were trying to do.

```
// This is your left-hand column container
// Note how I see 100vh, that just makes it as tall as your viewport
.banner .row .banner-left,.col-sm-8{
    background:url(http://www.wgcafe.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/a-vintage-red-background-with-a-crisscross-mesh-pattern-and-grunge-stains-wanlop-sonngam.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    max-height: 800px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This is still broken.

Comment: Did you look at the codepen example? What's broken in that?

Answer (score -1):

Set the margin on the "banner-right-top" and "banner-right-bottom" to 0 !important;